# Play a sound file when connecting to the Internet?

Tags: sound, internet, network-manager, internet-connection, autostart

Is it possible to play a certain sound file whenever Ubuntu connects to the Internet?

The sound should play when Ubuntu begings to try to connect after starting up the PC, after manually disconnecting/reconnecting with the Network Manager, when reconnecting after 24 hour disconnects, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Someone at ubuntuforums made a python script to play sounds when it connects or loose connection. It was probably made for Ubuntu 10.04, so i don't know if it will work with newer versions.

Here's the link to the original [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1490776).